# I can't update in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my error:

```
.../mydir/mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4719
  const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "628601191fc717b2266ce54d " (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"
    at model.Query.exec (/home/hasina/Bureau/node-complete/ch13-mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4719:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (/home/hasina/Bureau/node-complete/ch13-mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4818:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"628601191fc717b2266ce54d "',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '628601191fc717b2266ce54d ',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
      at new BSONTypeError (/home/hasina/Bureau/node-complete/ch13-mongoose/node_modules/bson/lib/error.js:41:28)
      at new ObjectId (/home/hasina/Bureau/node-complete/ch13-mongoose/node_modules/bson/lib/objectid.js:66:23)
      at castObjectId (/home/hasina/Bureau/node-complete/ch13-mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast/objectid.js:24:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (/home/hasina/Bureau/node-complete/ch13-mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:245:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (/home/hasina/Bureau/node-complete/ch13-mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1189:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (/home/hasina/Bureau/node-complete/ch13-mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1623:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (/home/hasina/Bureau/node-complete/ch13-mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1613:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/home/hasina/Bureau/node-complete/ch13-mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1590:20)
      at cast (/home/hasina/Bureau/node-complete/ch13-mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:344:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (/home/hasina/Bureau/node-complete/ch13-mongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:5141:12),
  valueType: 'string'
}
```

Node.js v17.8.0

Comment: can you show your code to give proper answer? update your question and add some code where you are facing problem.

Comment: There is a space at the end of that ID.

Comment: there is a whitespace in the objectId value ("628601191fc717b2266ce54d ") which causes this issue. try again after removing that whitespace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra blank space at the end of the id, remove that and it should work fine.

In case it still gives an error try converting the string id to ObjectId by writing `mongoose.type.ObjectId(YourStringVariable)`